# Should I ever use the returned response of a dispatched action in react-redux? Or always use useSelector?

Tags: reactjs, redux

May I ask if I should always use useSelector or are there situations where I can/should use the returned response of my dispatched action for react-redux? For example,should I do:

Case 1:

```
dispatch(signinUser(signInValues)).then((response) => {
        setMessage(response.payload.message);
        setUserData(response.payload.userData);
        setAuthResult(response.payload.auth);
      });
```

OR

Case 2:

```
const message = useSelector(state => state.userReducer.message)
const userData = useSelector(state => state.userReducer.userData)
const auth = useSelector(state => state.userReducer.auth)
...
const someFunction = () => {
  dispatch(signinUser(signInValues));
}
```

Comment: Best practice is to use `useSelector` so that the data is always up-to-date, e.g. if the data gets updated elsewhere (middleware, other action, etc).